# how to generate custom Auth token from api key

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am looking at the documentation at
[https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/][1]

for how to exchange firebase id and refresh token with my API key.
In the documentation, I found the sample code and some explaination as below,

```
curl 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-binary '{"token":"[CUSTOM_TOKEN]","returnSecureToken":true}'

In the example above, you would replace [API_KEY] with the Web API Key of your Firebase project, [CUSTOM_TOKEN] with the generated custom Auth token.
```

Anyone know how can I get the "custom Auth Token" as mentioned in the above sample?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think it is explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

And if you need to cook up something yourself then specifically: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library